# How can I render title attribute in img tag conditionally?

Tags: html, twig, octobercms

I'm trying to render a title Attribute in an HTML image tag conditionally with twig (in October CMS).

I tried following with `attributes.setAttribute`, but failed:

```
<img class="my-class" src="{{ myImage.path }}" {{ myImage.title ? attributes.setAttribute('title', myImage.title) : {} }}>
```

Is there any better way to do that? Or do I really have to do this one:

```
{% if myImage.title %}
   <img class="my-class" src="{{ myImage.path }}" title="{{ myImage.title }}">
{% else %}
   <img class="my-class" src="{{ myImage.path }}">
{% endif %}
```

I'm using twig in octoberCMS...

Comment: attributes.setAttribute attributes is not defined.  try this.setAttribute

Comment: Do you really need to not have the title attribute there?  If myImage.title is an empty string you can completely forgo using a condition within the html.  It'll render a title that is empty, which would be the same, functionally, as not having a title at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the below code

```
{% set titleAttribute =  myImage.title ? 'title="' ~ myImage.title ~ '"' : '' %}
<img class="my-class" src="{{ myImage.path }}" {{titleAttribute|raw}} />
```

> **OR inline version**

```
<img 
    class="my-class" 
    src="{{ myImage.path }}" 
    {{(myImage.title ? 'title="' ~ myImage.title ~ '"' : '')|raw}} 
/>
```

if any doubt please comment.

Comment: You don't need the extra `: ''` in twig

Comment: I added there because if the user wants to add a default title or something they can have an option, otherwise they get confused if they want to add and do not see any way to do it.
so it's better to add it there. as everybody is not well aware of twig

Comment: True, was just a note